# JSON wont show mysql data correctly :using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

i want to connect to a database server using php , and then echo the data as JSON so later i can use it in android but JSON shows `/` as `\/` for example
if http://www.google.com/ was in the database 
if shows it as

```
"http:\/\/www.google.com\/" .
```

i made connections and all and here is how i fetch the data

```
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
$array[] = $row;
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: You must have added slashes before placing in the database, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: i use that after the while , on the row string , it say's u must use it on a string not an array , i dont know where to put it

Comment: either you're on a stone-age PHP with register_globals enabled, or you're double-escaping going into the DB or pulling out of the db.

Comment: and i didnt know JSON encoded in that way , sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid json and the correct way to encode it, see http://codepad.viper-7.com/6PbdmJ

When you decode it in for example [javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/UCVSL/) or [php](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Cue1jn), you will get your original URL back:

javascript:

```
JSON.parse('"http:\/\/www.google.com\/"');
```

php:

```
var_dump(json_decode(json_encode('http://www.google.com/')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode you json ... run that PHP example and you will understand what i mean:

```
$encode = json_encode("https://www.google.com/");

echo $encode;

echo "<br />";

echo json_decode($encode,true);
```

so, if you sending encoded json, you should decode it in android to use it properly.

This link should help:
[How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)